# Page can't be displayed with IIS and SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, windows-server-2012, ssl-certificate

I have a single site hosted in IIS 8. I have two site bindings. One is for HTTP, the other is for HTTPS. HTTP is on port 80 with All Unassigned addresses, I left host name blank. HTTPS is on port 443 bound to All Unassigned addresses, and I left the host name blank. I have tried using a self signed certificate and one that was signed by our domain's root CA.

On the server if I use IIS to navigate to the site, it works just fine. My development machine works if I browse to it with HTTP, but HTTPS failed with "This page can't be displayed." I've tried using the host name and the IP to navigate to it, same problem either way.

Any idea what may be causing this?

- I've tried starting/stopping the site and IIS itself.
- The "Page can't
  be displayed" message happens with IE.
- Firefox says "The connection
  was reset".
- Chrome gives the error code "ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED"
- When I view the traffic from Wireshark, I see a single "Client Hello" packet going from my dev machine to the server. The server doesn't send anything in response.
- When I run Fiddler (Which has HTTPS decryption enabled), IE is able to navigate to the site properly. Which makes me think there's something weird with the certificate.

Comment: Don't use Windows XP?

Comment: @MichaelHampton My development machine is Windows 7, the server is Windows Server 2012. No XP machines are involved.

Comment: Does the IIS log spit out anything in particular? You may have to wireshark your client to figure out where the connection's breaking. Note that Firefox does not obey domain CAs that were pushed over AD to be trusted.

Comment: @NathanC No, nothing useful in the logs. I would expect Firefox to ask me if I want to trust the certificate, that's what I normally see happen due to not trusting the domain CA. I'll update the question with what I found from Wireshark in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier this morning I had disabled my Kaspersky anti-virus due to an unrelated issue. A few minutes ago I turned Kaspersky on and then my site started working again!

I've never seen that behavior before. Almost all of the time having AV running is the problem, not the solution.

Comment: Is that on the client machine or server?

Comment: @CeleryMan it's the client end where the AV is. It messes with the certificates so it can inspect your HTTPS traffic.